# Any way to list my unanswered questions on all Stack Exchange sites?

Tags: feature-request, unanswered-questions, question-lists

I've been asking quite a few questions on several Stack Exchange sites, and I'm finding it harder and harder to keep track of them all.

Is there any way/place to see a listing of all my questions with **no answer accepted** on all of the Stack Exchange (2.0) sites? <del>Or even just per site?</del> If not, are there any plans to implement such a feature?

Although Jeff offered an answer, I don't feel it's the answer to my question; as far I'm aware there still is no way to list only my **unanswered** questions.

Comment: You could use the Chrome extension StackStalker to keep track of your own questions, but it doesn't work on the newer sites (AFAIK)

Comment: I don't think I've ever even used any of the "old" sites. Guess I _am_ pretty new here. @Ivo

Answer (score 9):

I don't know of a good way to do this across *all* sites, but for any *one* site you can simply search using the `hasaccepted` operator and specifying your userID (or `me`) as the user.

#### Examples

- [`hasaccepted:0 user:me`](https://superuser.com/search?q=hasaccepted%3A0+user%3Ame)
- [`hasaccepted:0 user:56977`](https://superuser.com/search?q=hasaccepted%3A0+user%3A56977)

Comment: That's certainly a start. Thank you.

Comment: Likewise, @oKtosiTe: [`answers:0 user:me`](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=answers%3A0+user%3Ame)

Answer (score 8):

This is planned for http://stackexchange.com -- to have a global profile with "greatest hits" of your best questions and answers across all sites.

edit: this is now complete per https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/04/stack-exchange-network-profiles/

Comment: That's good to hear! Looking forward to any updates or additional information.

Comment: On second thought, perhaps you're referring to the "top" questions. What I'm looking for is a listing of only _open_ questions. Is that in the works too?

Comment: Still wondering if a listing of **open questions** is in the pipeline...

Comment: This still does not answer my question.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question.

Comment: Doesn't answer the question at all!

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to list these with a [SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/810881/networkwide-questions-without-accepted-answer-per-account), if you accept the fact that SEDE data is refreshed once a week, on Sunday morning. You'll need your network account ID, which you can find [here](https://stackexchange.com/users/current).

For reference, here is the complete query:

```sql
-- result table, don't rename and keep the site column
create table #results (site nvarchar(250), id int, title nvarchar(250), answercount int);

declare @sql nvarchar(max) = ''   -- holds build up sql string

-- build one biq union sql, for each db
select @sql = @sql 
+ iif( len(@sql) > 1 
     , 'union'
     , 'insert into #results'
) +
-- here goes the per site query, fully qualify the database objects
N'
select ''' + name + '''
     , p.id, p.title, p.answercount
from ' + quotename(name) + '.dbo.posts as p
inner join ' + quotename(name) + '.dbo.users as u on p.owneruserid = u.id
where p.posttypeid = 1
  and p.acceptedanswerid IS NULL
  and u.accountid = ' + CAST(##AccountId:int## AS nvarchar) + ''
from sys.databases
where database_id > 5
-- and (name not like '%.Meta' or name = 'StackExchange.Meta')

-- AccountId: The global account ID of the user, which you can find in the URL of their network profile. Visit this link: https://stackexchange.com/users/current to see your own ID.

-- execute it
exec (@sql)

SELECT
  LOWER('https://' +
    IIF(PATINDEX('%.Mathoverflow%', site) > 0,
    IIF(PATINDEX('%.Meta', site) > 0, 'meta.mathoverflow.net', 'mathoverflow.net'),
      IIF(PATINDEX('%.Ubuntu%', site) > 0,
      IIF(PATINDEX('%.Meta', site) > 0, 'meta.askubuntu.com', 'askubuntu.com'),
        IIF(PATINDEX('StackExchange.%', site) > 0,
          CASE SUBSTRING(site, 15, 200)
          WHEN 'Audio' THEN 'video'
          WHEN 'Audio.Meta' THEN 'video.meta'
          WHEN 'Beer' THEN 'alcohol'
          WHEN 'Beer.Meta' THEN 'alcohol.meta'
          WHEN 'CogSci' THEN 'psychology'
          WHEN 'CogSci.Meta' THEN 'psychology.meta'
          WHEN 'Garage' THEN 'mechanics'
          WHEN 'Garage.Meta' THEN 'mechanics.meta'
          WHEN 'Moderators' THEN 'communitybuilding'
          WHEN 'Moderators.Meta' THEN 'communitybuilding.meta'
          WHEN 'Photography' THEN 'photo'
          WHEN 'Photography.Meta' THEN 'photo.meta'
          WHEN 'Programmers' THEN 'softwareengineering'
          WHEN 'Programmers.Meta' THEN 'softwareengineering.meta'
          WHEN 'Vegetarian' THEN 'vegetarianism'
          WHEN 'Vegetarian.Meta' THEN 'vegetarianism.meta'
          WHEN 'Writers' THEN 'writing'
          WHEN 'Writers.Meta' THEN 'writing.meta'
          ELSE SUBSTRING(site, 15, 200)
          END + '.stackexchange.com',
          IIF(PATINDEX('StackOverflow.%', site) > 0,
            CASE SUBSTRING(site, 15, 200)
            WHEN 'Br' THEN 'pt'
            WHEN 'Br.Meta' THEN 'pt.meta'
            ELSE SUBSTRING(site, 15, 200)
            END + '.stackoverflow.com',
            IIF(PATINDEX('%.Meta', site) > 0,
              'meta.' + SUBSTRING(site, 0, PATINDEX('%.Meta', site)) + '.com',
              site + '.com'
            )
          )
        )
      )
    )
    )
    + '/q/' + CAST(id AS NVARCHAR)
    + '|' + title,
    answercount AS [Number of answers]
  FROM #results
  ORDER BY answercount DESC
```