# How to see all my SE unanswered questions

Tags: feature-request, answers, search, accepted-answer

I want to be able to see all questions that I have not yet accepted as answers on all SE sites that I use (20 currently) so that I ensure I keep on top of answers. I don't believe there is any way to do this without going into each site?

Comment: any comment, any answer ?

Comment: My SE site count is now up to 23...

Comment: [Any way to list my unanswered questions on all Stack Exchange sites?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73775/any-way-to-list-my-unanswered-questions-on-all-stack-exchange-sites)