# Add the ability to search for my unanswered questions across all sites

Tags: feature-request, unanswered-questions

I know how to search for my unanswered questions in a given site:

> user:me hasaccepted:no

But I would like to do this across all sites.  How can this be done, if it's possible?  If not, then could this be a feature request?

---

**Edit**:

The conclusion at [Any way to list my unanswered questions on all Stack Exchange sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/73775/287826), which all the dupes point to (directly or indirectly), seems to be: No, it's not possible. So I guess I'm proposing a feature request. How do I do that?

Comment: @Glorfindel - Thanks for the suggestion.  Your link eventually led me to an open question: see edit.

Comment: Your best bet currently is a SEDE query: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/810881/networkwide-questions-without-accepted-answer-per-account?AccountId=200040

Comment: And the 'conclusion' is already a [feature-request], so it's still a duplicate.

Comment: The original one, with 30+ upvotes, is already a feature request. There is nothing more we can do.